# Are these fields equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, solution-verification

> Let  $\zeta_3$ be the third root of unity.
>
> 1) Does it hold that: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\zeta_3)$ ?
>
> 2) Does it hold that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3)$?

My attempt for 1) is to compute the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\zeta_3$ as $p(x)=x^4+2x^3-x^2-2x+7$
which is of degree 4. But since $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3):\mathbb{Q}|=6$ these can't be equal. Is my proof correct?

For the second one I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\zeta_3$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$ since $x^3 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$. So its degree is $2$ not $3$.

For 2) you can do the same kind of thing. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2 \zeta_3$ is $x^3 - 2$ so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2 \zeta_3) \ne \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)$. It's a 3-dimensional subspace of a 6-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Comment: Ok so my proof for 1) is wrong then, but then what can I do for 1)? I have only shown that these are

Comment: @onanisland45 Both $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\zeta_3)$ are 4-dimensional vector spaces and one is contained in the other so they're equal.

Comment: @TrevorGunn How can we say easily that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\zeta_3)$ has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? I don't see how $p(x)$ is irreducible

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Modern_methods @Menezio If you already know that $\sqrt{2}, \zeta_3$ and $\sqrt 2 \zeta_3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the naïve approach of squaring $\sqrt{2} + \zeta_3$, rearranging, squaring, etc. will produce the minimal polynomial. Behind the scenes, what you're doing is computing the matrix for multiplication by $\sqrt{2} + \zeta_3$ (an integer matrix) and computing its minimal polynomial. You need to know that $1, \sqrt{2}, \zeta_3, \sqrt 2 \zeta_3$ is a basis for this matrix to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a standard trick for this kind of problem. You have obviously that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)\supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} +\zeta_3)$. Now we show the other containment; we have:
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \sqrt{2} +\zeta_3 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad (\alpha - \sqrt{2})^3 = \zeta_3^3
\end{equation}
Using $\zeta_3^3=1$ and doing the computation we have:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{\alpha^3+6\alpha-1}{3\alpha^2+2}
\end{equation}
Then $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} +\zeta_3)$. Having $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} +\zeta_3)$ we also have $\zeta_3\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} +\zeta_3)$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} +\zeta_3)\supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_3)$ and the equality.

2) $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$ since its minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3$ is $(x^3-2)$ that is irreducible for Eisenstein criterion. $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$ for the same reason above and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ because its minimum polynomial is $(x^2+x+1)$. Since $2$ and $3$ are coprime $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3)$.